# Angular ui-router dependency required in one submodule but not all?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the following plunkr, can anyone explain why I have to inject 'ui.router' into the first listed submodule, but not any of the subsequent submodules?

http://plnkr.co/edit/nCBeMAKrxvL9CHvLzRdL?p=preview

I thought the ui.router dependency would be available to every submodule after doing this:
`angular.module('myapp', ["myapp.route1", "myapp.route2", "ui.router"])`

Instead, i have to include `ui.router` in the first listed dependency (in this case `myapp.route`):
`angular.module('myapp.route1', ["ui.router"])`

but not in `myapp.route2`:
`angular.module('myapp.route2', [])`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The loading order depends on the order of declared dependencies, so

```
angular.module('myapp', ["myapp.route1", "myapp.route2", "ui.router"])
```

means that `"myapp.route1"` loads first (in *config phase* - this doesn't apply to run-phase), and it also loads `"ui.router"`. And, so, when `"myapp.route2"` loads, `"ui.router"` service are already loaded.

Changing the order of declared dependencies breaks this.

So, clearly, you should not rely on this. **Each module should declare its own dependencies.**

Comment: how would this work if you were writing a ui framework, such as ui.bootstrap? when using it, you only have to declare `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency due to the fact that all other dependencies (ui.bootstrap.accordion, ui.bootstrap.alert, etc.) are available via `ui.bootstrap`. At least that's what i can gather from the source code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you depend on module `"Foo"` you need to declare it. Module `"Foo"`, in turn, can have any number of dependencies which you shouldn't care about - Angular would resolve them accordingly. So, in your question, `"myapp.route2"` depends on `"ui.router"` (since it uses `$stateProvider`), so you should declare it and not rely on `"myapp.route1"` to include it.

Comment: so if i add a module as a dependency, that module and its dependencies are accessible, correct? in this case, ui.router and route.1 are both dependencies of the same module and should therefore be injected...?

Comment: @CoryDorning, I'm not sure what you're asking... "...therefore be injected" into what? Why complicate? Each module just needs to reason about its own immediate dependencies. `route1` uses `ui.router`, `route2` uses `ui.router`, `myapp` uses `route1`, `route2`, and `ui.router` - so, each module declares what it uses. Don't make assumptions about what other modules depend on and whether they were loaded